# Ubuntu does not recognize Ctrl key after recent upgrade

Tags: keyboard, keys

A recent system upgrade in 14.04 disabled the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in my Asus K55VM-SX086D Laptop. Initially there was some problem where the screen used to go blank when pressing the ctrl key when I was using 13.10, but somehow after upgrade to 14.04 it was working fine. However after the recent upgrade its not working again.

I have checked the default US keyboard layout and it does not seem to recognize the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Please help.

Do let me know steps that I can follow to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Fire up a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T, then type in this command: `xev`. It should tell you every time you input a key. If it doesn't respond to the key, it's a problem with the keyboard. If it does respond with something like a keycode of 37 (you'll need to look at the output of the terminal for this), comment back and I'll look into it further. :)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewFischer,  I tried using xev. The system does not recognize both the Ctrl keys.

Answer (score 1):

I used xmodmap to map the menu key to Control key as a last resort. The script used is as follows:

```
clear control
keycode 135 = Control_R
add control = Control_R
```

The above script was saved in  a `~/.Xmodmap` file and called using the command:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

to enable the new key binding. This can also be set up at startup.